# Rank of a Matrix power

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Say the rank of a matrix drops for all powers up to $n$
$$\text{rank}A^n< \text{rank} A^{n-1} < \ldots <\text{rank} A$$

Now suddenly $\text{rank} A^n = \text{rank} A^{n+1}$. Does the following implication hold true then
$$ \text{rank}A^n = \text{rank}A^{n+k} \,, \forall \, k \in \mathbb{N}$$

I am asking this to know when to stop looking for the next  vektor in a Jordan chain.

Comment: Have you tried to write your matrix in Jordan-normal form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we are allowed to use Jordan canonical form, the answer is obviously yes, as $n$ must be the size of the maximal Jordan block with $0$ on the diagonal.

To show this directly, we have $\text{rank}A^n=\text{rank}A^{n+1}$ is equivalent to $\text{im}(A^{n+1})=\text{im}(A^n)$, in other words, $A$ is a bijection from $\text{im}(A^n)$ to itself. Now it follows that $A^{k}$ is a bijection from $\text{im}(A^n)$ to itself.

Answer (score 0):

Rank is the dimension of the column space (i.e. the image of the linear transformation).

It is always true that $Col(A^{m+1}) \subseteq Col(A^m)$, or that $im \ A^{m+1} \subseteq im \ A^m $ (The more general fact that $Col(AB)\subseteq Col(A)$ is not difficult to prove.)

So let's consider sequence of images $V \supseteq im\ A \supseteq im \ A^2 \supseteq...$

Initially, $A $ reduces (or maintains, if it is an isomorphism) the dimension of $V$ to that of its image, then $A^2$ further reduces the dimension to $im \ A^2$ via $A$ restricted to $im \ A $ (since after the first application only $im \ A$ is nonzero, and linear maps send zero to zero). So when the sequence stabilises, $im \ A^m = im \ A^{m+1} $, this essentially means that $A$ restricted to $im \ A^m$ is an isomorphism. Since any power of an isomorphism is an isomorphism, no further iterations of $A$ will reduce the dimension.

Note also that by the rank-nullity theorem, as the rank decreases the kernel increases, and the two sequences stabilise at the same step.
[image: The expansion of kernel and reduction of image with each application of A]